# Dataframe - Add multiple together with sometimes different index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes that have sometimes different index but still important datasets. combining them with merge or concat doesn't work and leaves to duplicate indexes or removes some of the index values where they are not contained in each of them.

They look like this,

```
index - potatoes
a     -    1
b     -    2
d     -    3
index - eggs
a     -    1
c     -    2
d     -    3
index - bacon
b     -    1
c     -    1
d     -    3
```

The output I want is

```
index - potatoes - eggs - bacon
a     -    1     -  1   - NaN
b     -    2     - NaN  -  1
```

Whats the best pathway?

Comment: what happened to `c` and `d`? Are these dataframes or series?

Comment: dataframes - they are separate key-values, so NaN for some index types

Comment: It is unclear to me

Comment: Why does concat not work? `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

Comment: Actually it did work with axis, lol, so simple thanks